# In a UFD $R$, $a/b \in FF[R]$ and a root of monic polynomial implies it is in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Theorem.  *Let $R$ be a UFD, $f \in R[X]$ a monic polynomial and $\alpha$ is in the field of fractions of $R$. Then if $f(a)=0$, $a \in R$.*

*What I have done:*
Let $f= x^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+ a_0 $ and $\alpha = a/b $, then since $R$ is a UFD, we can factorize $a$ and $b$. After cancelling out the common factors let us say $\alpha=u/v$. $f(\alpha)=0 \implies \cfrac{u^n}{v^n} +\dots +a_1\cfrac{u}{v}+a_0 =0$. Multiply both sides by $v^n;$

$$u^n +a_{n-1}u^{n-1}v + \dots +a_1uv^{n-1} +a_0v^{n}=0.$$

Now I am stuck, how should I continue? Can I say that $u$ is algebraic over $R[\alpha]$ for instance?

Comment: The \dots control sequence behaves in some contexts like \ldots and in some like \cdots, thus: A+\dots B yields $A+\dots B$ and A+\dots+B yields $A+\dots+B.$ If I'm not mistaken, the latter is standard in fastidious typesetting and I changed it in the question. $\qquad$

Comment: This is basically prop. 35 in Pete L. Clark's notes on factorization in integral domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just there.

If $d$ is an irreducible divisor of $v$, then $d$ will divide all the terms of your last equation except for the leading $u^n$ and only that one, which is a contradiction (unless $d$ is a unit). Hence, $v$ is a unit.